# CSS animation disables click on a div when used with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, css, css-animations

I have this "select a cake" page **[HERE](http://codeandcode.co/demo/BrowniePoint/HTML/V2/cake-buying-guide.html)**, now when I select a cake and click next, a new page is loaded through AJAX and the boxes have a `fadeInUp` animation but the boxes become unclickable, Why ? If I remove the animations it works fine, basically the AJAX code that loads the next page is below:

```
$(document).on('click' , '.btn-next' , function(){ 

    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
        return false;
    }

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #cake-selection-content';
    $('#cake-selection-content').animate({ 'opacity' : 1 },loadContent);
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#cake-selection-content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#cake-selection-content').show('normal' , setTimeout(function(){
            runWaypoints(); 
        }, 1000));
    }
    return false;
});
```

Now if you notice closely there is this function `shownewcontent()` that looks as follows:

```
function showNewContent() {
    $('#cake-selection-content').show('normal' , setTimeout(function(){
        runWaypoints(); 
    }, 1000));
}
```

And inside that function there is the `runWaypoints();` function  that actually adds the animations.

So as I said, if I don't add the animations the box on the next page are clickable, but if I do add the CSS animations then the boxes become unclickable, Why?

Comment: Ur example link points to `localhost` which is accessible only to u. Please provide a precise and concise JSFiddle demo :)

Comment: @AhsN and harry lol sorry now i have corrected it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the animation seems to bring the `figure` element above the `label` element which is your trigger to access the radio button. Since the `figure` is above the `label` it is not allowing you to access the `label` and thus the click event doesn't happen.

It is difficult to exactly narrow down the problem in your page (without having a fiddle playground) but I assume that it might have something to do with how layer creation works for accelerated rendering. In this animation, you are animating the `opacity` of the element which means a new layer is created for this `figure` element and it is possibly getting placed above the `label`.

One solution would be to add a `z-index` to the `label` element.

```
.input-whts-the-occcaion > label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Or, you can set `pointer-events: none` to the `figure` element so that you can access the `label`.

```
.bp-help-buy-cake .whats-the-occasion .help-buy-cake-box {
    width: 255px;
    height: 255px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton harry :D